# Which Stack Exchange site for asking about printers & accessories?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site for asking about printers (devices) and printing accessories (home & small business use)?

Comment: What do you want to know about printers? Repair them? How they work? How to build one yourself? How to install or configure one? How to solve an issue you have while printing?

Comment: I have a question related with "a product, service or learning material recommendation" which is not on [superuser.com topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). I must find some other site ([Quora](https://quora.com/), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/), etc.) to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've [edited it out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/334206/revisions), but you tagged your question [printing](/questions/tagged/printing). When you hover over the tag (or tap it if you're using a touch device, or the tag is used as markup in a post like this), it says:

> For questions about printing parts of Stack Exchange posts. For general questions about printing, visit Super User.

So you've answered your own question :) But it's worth noting that [3D printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) has its own site, and not all printing questions are on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/); check their [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question, and remember to [search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer+or+printing) first.

Comment: And if you're looking to purchase a printer and have a list of criteria it needs to meet, you can try asking on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), though it isn't exactly the most active site on the network.